# Facebook Audience Network returns error "Ad was re-loaded too frequently"

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network

I try to add Facebook banner to my Android App. It works good with my LG D-405, but returns "Ad was re-loaded too frequently" with Samsung Galaxy S5.

```
adView = new AdView(getActivity(), "-------", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                if(getActivity()!=null) {
                    ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getDefaultTracker().send(
                            new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                                    .setCategory("Facebook AdView")
                                    .setAction("error")
                                    .setLabel(adError.getErrorMessage())
                                    .setValue((long) adError.getErrorCode())
                                    .build()
                    );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                if(!layout.getChildAt(2).equals(adView)) {
                    layout.addView(adView, 2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50.getWidth() * MainActivity.density), (int) (AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50.getHeight() * MainActivity.density)));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

            }
        });
        //adView.disableAutoRefresh();
        adView.loadAd();
```

Comment: you got any solution to this?

Comment: Hey man, do you know the reverse of disableAutoRefresh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too got the same issue and the it seems that you must have the Facebook app installed on the device and have logged in within the last 30 days.

Also, I found this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31628715/3036759)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution if you are using emulator:

1. in logcat search for `AdSettings.addTestDevice`. You will find something like `"AdSettings.addTestDevice("3b656c58-53ab-43a8-a0d6-d1f82abdf251");"`
2. Copy this line to your code.

You are done.

Answer (score 1):

According to facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing/checklist-errors#errors), ad request frequency has certain limit and you should wait 30 minutes before making an other ad request if you received this error.

> Code=1002 “Load Too Frequently”
>   Ad Requests are based on a combination of:
>   Device ID
>   Placement ID
>   Display Format (Banner, Interstitial, Native)
>   Your application should attempt to make another request after 30 minutes. We also suggest adjusting your Refresh Rate or Request Rate.